# SyntaxError inside keras package

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, syntax-error, image-segmentation

I'm trying to run a segmentation package from Github and I'm running into an error with keras and tensorflow. I get a a syntax error in a file from the keras package. I suspect it may be a compatibility issue, but I've reinstalled keras and tensorflow to no avail.

```
(base) Karthicks-MacBook-Pro:ROP_Research-master karthick$ python2 run_augmented_IROP.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mainScript.py", line 9, in <module>
    import opticDiscDetector as odd
  File "/Users/karthick/Downloads/ROP_Research-master/iROPASSISTPackage-master/code/opticDiscDetector.py", line 12, in <module>
    from keras.models import model_from_json
  File "/Users/karthick/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from keras import models
  File "/Users/karthick/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 19, in <module>
    from keras import backend
  File "/Users/karthick/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/keras/backend.py", line 3838
    op = tf.print(
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is what pip2 list returns:

```
absl-py                                0.13.0
altgraph                               0.10.2
asn1crypto                             0.24.0
astor                                  0.8.1
backports.weakref                      1.0.post1
bdist-mpkg                             0.5.0
bonjour-py                             0.3
cachetools                             3.1.1
certifi                                2021.5.30
cffi                                   1.14.3
chardet                                4.0.0
cryptography                           2.9.2
enum34                                 1.1.6
funcsigs                               1.0.2
functools32                            3.2.3.post2
future                                 0.17.1
futures                                3.3.0
gast                                   0.2.2
google-auth                            1.34.0
google-auth-oauthlib                   0.4.1
google-pasta                           0.2.0
grpcio                                 1.39.0
h5py                                   2.10.0
idna                                   2.10
ipaddress                              1.0.22
keras                                  2.6.0
Keras-Applications                     1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing                    1.1.2
macholib                               1.5.1
Markdown                               3.1.1
matplotlib                             1.3.1
mock                                   3.0.5
modulegraph                            0.10.4
numpy                                  1.16.6
oauthlib                               3.1.0
opt-einsum                             2.3.2
pip                                    20.3.4
protobuf                               3.17.3
py2app                                 0.7.3
pyasn1                                 0.4.8
pyasn1-modules                         0.2.8
pycparser                              2.19
pyobjc-core                            2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Accounts              2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook           2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit        2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC       2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Automator             2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork             2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa                 2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration         2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreData              2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation          2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreText              2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices    2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-EventKit              2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling     2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents              2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit        2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins      2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage        2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping 2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices        2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Message               2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory         2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes       2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PubSub                2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-QTKit                 2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Quartz                2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver           2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge       2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit             2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement     2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Social                2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices          2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration   2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-WebKit                2.5.1
pyOpenSSL                              19.0.0
pyparsing                              2.0.1
python-dateutil                        1.5
pytz                                   2013.7
requests                               2.26.0
requests-oauthlib                      1.3.0
rsa                                    4.5
scipy                                  1.2.2
setuptools                             41.0.1
six                                    1.12.0
tensorboard                            2.1.0
tensorflow                             2.1.0
tensorflow-estimator                   2.1.0
termcolor                              1.1.0
tf                                     1.0.0
urllib3                                1.26.6
Werkzeug                               1.0.1
wheel                                  0.33.1
wrapt                                  1.12.1
xattr                                  0.6.4
```

I'm fairly new to python and have never used keras/tensorflow before.

Comment: Why are you using Python 2.7? It reached its end-of-life on Jan 1, 2020, and is no longer supported. Many major projects have dropped support for it. New projects (and new learners) should use Python 3.

Comment: Additionally, you have not posted the complete error and traceback. Please [edit] your post and do so.

Comment: I tried running it in Python 3 but it uses many deprecated functions. This is a segmentation algorithm from Github that I'm trying to adapt to my use case. This is the original github: https://github.com/neu-spiral/iROPASSISTPackage

Comment: `print` is only a keyword in Python 2, so Python 3 (where it's a function) wouldn't call this an error (and any code causing this error was clearly not built to support Python 2). Perhaps you tried running it with the _wrong version of_ Python 3?

Comment: If you have to tf.print in python 2 then use `from __future__ import print_function`.
Still if the internal package is throwing error then you should consider using python3 and latest Tensorflow version to avoid multiple packages conflict.